# Unable to connect to sandbox using the MavensMate and Sublime Text

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

I have setup the mavensmate using MavensMate Desktop app and when I am trying to connect to the sandbox, I see the below error comes. Through web I can connect easily. I am using http://test.salesforce.com/

> Please check your username and password. If you still can't log in, contact your Salesforce administrator.

Could you please guide whats wrong here ? Even if I login successfully, but I can't see anything like Projects gets created.

```
2017-04-06 23:12:20> IEnableLogger: Failed to download url: https://mavensmate-app-auto-updater.herokuapp.com/update/channel/stable/win32_ia32/0.0.11-beta.7/RELEASES?id=MavensMate&localVersion=0.0.11-beta7&arch=amd64: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<LogIfThrows>d__35`1.MoveNext()
2017-04-06 23:12:20> FileDownloader: Downloading url: https://mavensmate-app-auto-updater.herokuapp.com/update/channel/stable/win32_ia32/0.0.11-beta.7/releases?id=mavensmate&localversion=0.0.11-beta7&arch=amd64
2017-04-06 23:12:20> IEnableLogger: Failed to download url: https://mavensmate-app-auto-updater.herokuapp.com/update/channel/stable/win32_ia32/0.0.11-beta.7/releases?id=mavensmate&localversion=0.0.11-beta7&arch=amd64: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

[image: Screen Capture]

Comment: Are you under corporate proxy?

Comment: I think, yes I am under corporate proxy

Comment: If you  are in windows OS, refer [this post](http://forcetrekker.blogspot.nl/2016/02/mavensmate-plugin-under-corporate-proxy-windows-7.html) for configuring the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your log, you're not even getting to the point where you're attempting to log-in to your sandbox. Instead, Maven's Mate is attempting to download some kind of update and is apparently unsuccessful.

```
Failed to download url: https://mavensmate-app-auto-updater.herokuapp.com/update/channel/stable/win32_ia32/0.0.11-beta.7/RELEASES?id=MavensMate&localVersion=0.0.11-beta7&arch=amd64: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

I recommend you visit the MavensMate Github repo and look for info on this error.